# how to create an array string to print list of elements in android

Tags: java, android, listview

Here I am going to print all the methods that are inside the class using reflection, so in a normal `JAVA` program it is going to print. But in `Android` layout it is displaying only one method:

```
public static void main() throws Exception{
    Log.i("Ramu","I am here displayM ");
    Class o =Class.forName("android.view.AbsSavedState");
    Method M[]=o.getMethods();
    for( i=0;i<M.length;i++)
        methodname = M[i].getName();
    Listview.your_array_list.add(methodname);
    Listview.your_array_list.add(methodname);
    Log.i("Ramu","methode name "+ M[i].getName());
    //System.out.println(M[i].getName());
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that you will only get the last methode stored in M with that for loop ?
    `for( i=0;i<M.length;i++) methodname = M[i].getName();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u forgot `{ }` of `for loop` dude just keep it in `{ }` and then try

```
for( i=0;i<M.length;i++)
{

        methodname = M[i].getName();
    Listview.your_array_list.add(methodname);
     Log.i("Ramu","methode name "+ M[i].getName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop ended the very next line of declaration and also u were printing only method name at at final index value after the loop completion. Try using braces, that will solve the problem. Check following code

```
public static void main() throws Exception{
    Log.i("Ramu","I am here displayM ");
    Class o =Class.forName("android.view.AbsSavedState");
    Method M[]=o.getMethods();
    for( i=0;i<M.length;i++){
        methodname = M[i].getName();
    Listview.your_array_list.add(methodname);
    Listview.your_array_list.add(methodname);
    Log.i("Ramu","methode name "+ M[i].getName());
}

    //System.out.println(M[i].getName());
}
```

Comment: if u found my answer helpful then please care to accept it!!

Answer (score 0):

You've forgot to put the brackets, that's you don't get expected output:

```
Class o = Class.forName("android.view.AbsSavedState");
Method M[] = o.getMethods();
for (int i = 0; i < M.length; i++) {
    methodname = M[i].getName();
    Listview.your_array_list.add(methodname);
    Log.i("Ramu", "method name " + methodname);
}
```